# php-fpm or nginx capping out?

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, amazon-ami

I'm using blitz.io to basically blast my site with traffic to see how my 'learning sysadmin' holds up under load. I realize this is as effective or relevant to real-world as a sledgehammer, but I really wanted to just see a comparison when I change a setting.

My setup in order of communication (all on Amazon EC2), Amazon Linux AMI

- 1x Amazon elastic load balancer
- 2x Nginx servers which upstream to...
- 1x Php-fpm server (soon to be 2x). Which connects to...
- 1x RDS mysql server

Everything is behind a VPC

For my testing, the site I am serving is a Wordpress installation with W3 Total Cache.

Originally I had 1x Nginx + 1x Php-fpm (1x Rds is implied) all as micro-servers. I believe I got 850 req/sec before I started getting a lot of time outs (times > 1000ms).

During this time, the CPU went to 100% on both phpfpm and nginx. So..

I then added a second nginx server. After that, I converted both nginx servers to 'large' as well as the php-fpm to 'large'.

I multiplied my php-fpm settings x5 and much to my dismay the tests were nearly identical... the only difference this time is both CPU and Memory went MAX about 5% on all 3 servers. It's like hardly ANY resources were being used. I looked in my logs for errors and didn't really see much...

I have looked at my settings many times and I know I'm missing something huge...

The site content for the wordpress section can be completely cachable... if I update anything on it I will clear the cache. Theres a second half to my site but its ALL static content, no db queries. I do use a php 'loader' script that loads in various content from include files but that's it.. pretty lightweight.

I have heard something about `ulimit` or rather.. could that be a problem?

I'm trying to do 6000 users over the course of 1 minute

My configs

#### Server 1: Nginx

```
nginx.conf

user  www www;

worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {

    server_tokens  off;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    sendfile        on;

    tcp_nopush      on;

    tcp_nodelay     off; 

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_disable      "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level   5;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_min_length   256;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_vary         on;
    gzip_types
      # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
      text/css
      text/plain
      text/x-component
      application/javascript
      application/json
      application/xml
      application/xhtml+xml
      application/x-font-ttf
      application/x-font-opentype
      application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      image/svg+xml
      image/x-icon;

    ssl_protocols              SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; 
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    upstream php {
        # ip_hash;
        server  10.0.0.210:9001;
    }

    include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

relevant nginx setting..

/etc/nginx/conf/cache-descriptors.conf

```
open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid    30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;
```

#### Server 2: php-fpm

php-fpm.conf

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf

[global]
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
log_level = notice

emergency_restart_threshold = 5
emergency_restart_interval = 2
```

php.ini

`In this file I honestly didnt change much in php.ini except for the CGI path setting for the nginx zero day exploit. Maybe one more setting or two but vanilla for the most part`

/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
[www]

listen = 9001

; # nginx-master, nginx-2
listen.allowed_clients = 10.0.0.248,10.0.0.155

user = www
group = www

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 500
pm.start_servers = 150
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 250
pm.max_requests = 1200

request_terminate_timeout = 30

slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

security.limit_extensions = .php

php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 0
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

If anyone has any ideas this would be greatly appreciated. I'm definitely hitting some kind of 'invisible limit' that I'm not seeing.

Thanks!

PS If you have any better way to benchmark I would be all ears..

screenshot of RDS is in the comment below (i kept it at micro)

here is what happened with test

[image: blitz]

Comment: Did you increase your database server? What are the database server stats like during this period?

Comment: I didn't increase RDS because there's hardly a dent in it (I assume because caching is doing all the work). Unless I'm reading this wrong (it's the 2nd big spike.. first one was from my first test): http://i.imgur.com/UszMGWT.png

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the limit is not anything to do with the capacity of the client performing the test rather than the server doing the work? Perhaps you ran out of available throughput for example.

Comment: Blitz.io is meant for load testing up to 100,000, so I dont think 6000 would be a problem :/

Comment: This is what happened http://i.imgur.com/72Aufcb.png

Comment: Do you have the address to the website in question?

Comment: what headers look like? ( lynx -head -source http://yoursite.com/typical_page/ )
Then 2x nginx for 1x php + 1x mysql dosen't make sense to me
1x nginx + 2x php + 2x mysql seems more like something sensible
checking on server running nginx settings for kernel.shmmax and net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max (you can reach up to 1 million connections)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're reaching limits yes, like number of ephemeral port range, number of max file descriptors opened, depletion of sockets, swapping out memory to disk, or even you're getting out of socket memory.

Look at /var/log/messages, dmesg, /proc/net/sockstat to look for clues on where your bottlenecks are.

Without logs it's hard to be of help.